# Почему "НАдевать", но "Обувать".

Tags: словообразование

Как известно, одевать — кого-то, надевать — на себя. Но почему этот же закон не относится к обуви? Почему в любом случае будет "обувать", даже если надеваешь обувь на себя? Почему не НАбувать?

Comment: См. также: [Есть ли в русском языке глагол “набуть”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/431257/177334)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Относится. Вернее относился. Существовало ещё не совсем забытое слово "набуть" (набувать) и причастие (оно же - прилагательное) "набутый".
Но оно вытеснено некогда ненормативным в данном значении "обувать". Полагаю, что тут сыграло еще и то, что слово "обувь" не воспринимается современным носителем как членимое на приставку "об" и корень -у(вь).  Впрочем, весьма вероятно, что скоро то же самое произойдёт с "надеть", все активнее вытесняемым просторечным "одеть".

В отношении степени нормативности - тут разные могут быть мнения. Пусть будет разговорным, не столь важно. Главное, думаю, дать объяснение.

Comment: Согласна. Даже те, кто знает, как правильно, в речи все равно ошибаются: обувь - обуть,  одежда - одеть

Answer (score -1):

Не в любом случае. МАС значению "надеть на ноги" ставит помету "разговорное":

[ОБУТЬ](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/37024/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)